# XML Tag exist or not in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to check if `<price-adjustments>` tag exist in XML below in Dataweave 2.0 in Mule 4. How to achieve this?

I am trying below but its giving me syntax error:

```
(payload.ns0#order.ns0#"product-lineitems".*ns0#"product-lineitem" map( e , lineindex ) -> {
     if(e.price-adjustments != null || e.price-adjustments != "") e."price-adjustments"."base-price" - (e."price-adjustments"."tax"/e."price-adjustments".quantity") else e.ns0#"base-price" - (e.ns0#"tax"/e.ns0#"quantity")
        
}
```

XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <order xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31" version="20.8" order-no="00002404">
            <order-date>2021-03-08T15:20:32.084Z</order-date>
            <product-lineitems>
                <product-lineitem>
                    <net-price>487.60</net-price>               
                </product-lineitem>
                <product-lineitem>
                    <net-price>53.72</net-price>               
                    <price-adjustments>
                        <price-adjustment>
                            <net-price>-53.72</net-price>                      
                        </price-adjustment>
                    </price-adjustments>
                </product-lineitem>
            </product-lineitems>
    </order>
```

Comment: Are you just going to check if price-adjustments exists in any of the product-lineitem or you need to check existence of the said field for each product-lineitem?

Comment: for for each product-lineitem

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload..*"product-lineitem" map {
            "calcResult($$)": if($.."price-adjustment"?) "some calc" else "some other calc"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.order."product-lineitems".*"product-lineitem" 
  map( e , lineindex ) ->
    if (e.."price-adjustments"? or e.."price-adjustments" != "") 
        e."price-adjustments"."base-price" - (e."price-adjustments".tax/e."price-adjustments".quantity)
    else 
        e."base-price" - (e.tax/e.quantity)
```

You could use the descendant selector and the Key present selector to search if the key is present through the entire XML.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-selectors

Edit: In your code, there are some syntax errors like:

- Using `||` instead of  `or`
- Returning an Object from the map without a `key:value` syntax (just remove the `{} in the map).

The script above doesn't work with the input that you gave because of "tax, "quantity" and "base-price" are not being set, but it doesn't contain syntax errors so you could continue working from that.

Comment: how does it work with the if-else condition?

Comment: I updated my question with what I was trying.